# Serve random image with Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have approx. 100.000 pictures and my goal is to generate a Django-powered webpage that displays one of those pictures at random every time the page loads (actually it's a bit more complicated, but that's my minimal example). My approach right now is as follows:

1. I put all 100.000 files into the static folder of my app.
2. I manually generate a database containing the paths to all images.
3. A URL-associated view randomly selects a database entry (i.e., a path) and generates the page from a template.

My template for the view looks like this:

```
...
<body>
<H1>'Hello World' from the template!</H1>
Here's a random image: "{{rImage}}"<p>
<canvas class="stream" id="canvas" style="z-index: 1; outline: 1px solid red;" width=505px height=336px></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var cxt = canvas.getContext("2d");

img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){};
img.src = "/static/rim/{{rImage}}";

cxt.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
</script>
</body>
...
```

{{rImage}} is the path to the random image. As you can see, I'm actually drawing the image to an HTML5 canvas with Javascript. Here's the corresponding Django view in Python:

```
def index(request):
    rImage = Images.objects.all()[random.randint(0, 100000)].relativeUrl
    template = loader.get_template('rim/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request,{'rImage':rImage})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Although that actually works, I'm pretty sure that I'm violating some fundamental design principles. Is it good practice to serve static images this way? Or should I add the entire images (instead of just the paths) directly to the database, e.g., with an ImageField? What's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: `ImageField` doesn't actually store the image in the database, but the path to the image, as well as other info. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#filefield) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#imagefield)

Comment: Serving the images as files from the file system is the right way to do this (never store images as binary blobs in a database -- for a  relatively strong definition of never).  100 000 files in a directory can become unmanageable, so maybe split it up to keep your sanity intact.  Drawing the image in a canavas seems strange in this small example, but I'm guessing you have a "real need".

Comment: You can reduce the size of your DB query by using `rImage = Images.objects.order_by('?')[0].relativeUrl`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought `ImageField` would be for file uploads at runtime only, but I have the images already, so I couldn't make sense out of the `uploadTo` parameter. Also, I wasn't sure if it is okay to use static images and display them in a dynamic way. Can I be sure that the browser doesn't try to cache all 100.000 files because he thinks they're all necessary to display the page correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented `ImageField` doesn't actually store images in database, it has links to images in filesystem and generates proper url to image for it's use in templates.

You can get random image using `rImage = Images.objects.order_by('?')[0]` but keep in mind that it can be expensive and slow operation depending on database backend you're using (e.g. mysql). Then you can pass image object to template and use `{{rImage.image_field.url}}` (image field handles url generation for you, just set proper values in your project settings)